Bind9 name/srv resolution with .local domain
I’ll start off by saying I am new to bind9 and I have inherited an environment that uses a .local domain.
I know that using .local is bad, but I cannot change it. It is what it is.
I have a requirement to use bind9 for local DNS caching (specifically for SRV records).
Each time I try dig it fails to fully resolve.
I see comment “WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS”
# dig prod.voip.local
; <<>> DiG 9.16.48-Debian <<>> prod.voip.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 48192
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: a11a15c488caedf7010000006667a78480d395b756e49357 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;prod.voip.local. IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 11 11:25:24 AEST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90

/etc/bind/named.conf.local
  GNU nano 5.4
//
// Do any local configuration here
//
zone "prod.voip.local" {
   type forward;
   forwarders {
    10.2.1.135; // Internal DNS servers
    10.2.129.135;
    10.2.1.136;
    10.2.129.136; };
};

I joined this forum to try and ask/comment on this other post Bind9 .local stub zone if they got a resolution, but have not enough rep to comment.
So I posted similar question instead.
So hopefully someone can point me if a helpful direction.
Thanks in advance of any help.

At least your .local subzone uses three-element names, which makes it somewhat distinguishable from mDNS. Not ideal, but not completely hopeless.
But the BIND is apparently responding with a SERVFAIL error.
Will the configured forwarders answer when your server asks? Test with dig:
dig prod.voip.local @10.2.1.135
dig prod.voip.local @10.2.129.135
dig prod.voip.local @10.2.1.136
dig prod.voip.local @10.2.129.136

What do the logs say?
You might want to add something like this to your named.conf.local for improved logging:
logging {
        // Predefined channels: default_syslog, default_debug, 
        // default_stderr and null.
        channel update_info {
                file "/var/log/named/update.log";
                severity  info;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-time     yes;
        };
        channel security_info    {
                file "/var/log/named/security.log";
                severity  info;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-time     yes;
        };
        channel query_log       {
                file "/var/log/named/query.log";
                severity info;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-time     yes;
        };
 
        category update { update_info; };
        category security { security_info; };
        category dnssec { security_info; };
        category queries { query_log; };
};

If you have rndc set up, use rndc querylog on to enable query logging for troubleshooting, and rndc querylog off to disable it, while BIND is running.

If your system is a RHEL or something else that uses SELinux, you'll need to assign appropriate SELinux labels to the log files:
semanage fcontext -a -t named_log_t '/var/log/named/.*\.log'
restorecon -rv /var/log/named


Debian and related distributions might have AppArmor instead, in which case you'll need to edit /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named to add the line:
/var/log/named/*.log rw,

and then run:
apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named

This will reload the main AppArmor profile for BIND9. It will have an #include that will pick up the corresponding file in the local/ subdirectory if it exists.

Thanks for the reply and help. If I specify one of the forwarders it seems to answer and work OK.
I have added your logging config to my /etc/bind/named.conf.local.
I have tried and failed to get the logging working by following numerous guides. Currently with all 3 files ownership as bind:bind and 777, but still fails to write anything to them.

How are the permissions of the directories on the path to the log file? If you run namei -l <path to a file>, you'll see the permissions of the file and all the directories on the path at once. If the logfile path includes a directory with no x permission applicable to the bind user, then that user cannot get through that directory to access the file at the end of the path.

Thanks for your patience and persistence with me. Here is example of permissions for /var/log/named/update.log and system info.
`namei -l /var/log/named/update.log
f: /var/log/named/update.log
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxr-xr-x root root log
drwxr-x--- bind bind named
-rwxrwxrwx bind bind update.log
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian `

Sorry I dont know how to format that correctly.

Ah, you have Debian. It has started using AppArmor, and it might be what's blocking you here as the permissions seem OK. See my edit above.

That /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named already had lines /var/log/named/** rw, and /var/log/named/ rw, but I added your /var/log/named/*.log rw, as well. Then executed apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named . I then performed dig again put still nothing in log files.
